# How to find unused images in public folder in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i have a big project with a lot of images in the public folder of react app, is there a way to find all the unused images and clean them up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue and this question led to me to search for answers.
I stumbled upon this [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/webpack-delete-unused-code-with-webpack-and-unused-files-webpack-plugin) which helped to partly resolve the issue.

The problem here is that, the plugin used in the video `unused-files-webpack-plugin` does not support Webpack 5. An [issue](https://github.com/tomchentw/unused-files-webpack-plugin/issues/39) was raised to update the plugin to support Webpack 5 but the author of the package hasn't issued an update.

A similar package that can be used is the `webpack-deadcode-plugin`. You can use the implementation from the video and substitute the `unused-files-webpack-plugin` with the `webpack-deadcode-plugin` making a few changes (such as to the `patterns` property which you would have to change to something like: `patterns: ['src/**/*.(png|jpg|jpeg)']` for your use case) to adapt the new plugin.

Edit: This answer assumes you are using webpack as your bundler.

Comment: You can check how I implemented the same on this [commit](https://github.com/BlackWind001/webpack-project/commit/4180aef96269d1820e40f29c2b5ad26eb84b8424) from one of my repositories.